# Vertical Spacing Between Figure Names from Different Chapters in Table of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, koma-script

I'm using the `chngcntr` package to prevent the figure numbering from restarting, in my `scrreprt`. Take a look at the following code:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
```

Although the numbering is not interrupted, at times, I get a little vertical space in the Table of Figures between the references, which again plays the role of a divisor between figures coming from different chapters. Is there a way to get rid of it?

In my `.lof` file for the Table of Figures, those lines happen to be the cause of this vertical space:

```
\addvspace {10\p@ }
\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax
\addvspace {10\p@ }
```

EDIT: A sample code to illustrate what I mean:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt,oneside,parskip=half]{scrreprt} 

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{scrhack} 

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures


\clearpage

\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics{image}
\caption{First Figure}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics{image}
\caption{First Figure}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics{image}
\caption{First Figure}
\label{fig3}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics{image}
\caption{First Figure}
\label{fig4}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics{image}
\caption{First Figure}
\label{fig5}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\includegraphics{image}
\caption{First Figure}
\label{fig6}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added a code sample.

Comment: My solution has a drawback: It's applied for the LoT as well.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Well in my case, that is not really a problem, so thank you, nonetheless.

Comment: I approved your edit, but I am not sure that works, since the spacing values are written at the time of `\chapter`, not when `\listoffigures` comes into action

Comment: Yep, you're right, I'm sorry.

Comment: `\KOMAoption{chapteratlists}{0pt}`

Comment: @ax1mx2: Thanks for unaccepting --- you can choose the other answer, of course

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, really no need to go into source code surfing here.

`\KOMAoption{chapteratlists}{0pt}`

will set the *chaptergap* to zero point. All lists controlled by package `tocbasic` are influenced.

Alternatively, you could use `\KOMAoption{listof}{nochaptergap}`.